# Laravel 5.3 and 5.4 Custom Route File

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-routing, laravel-5.4

According to the Laravel Documentation, in routing section, the files located in the route directory are automatically loaded by the framework.

> All Laravel routes are defined in your route files, which are located in the routes directory. These files are automatically loaded by the framework.

So, I tried to create another file in this directory called `auth.php` for handling my custom authentication routes. But, the routes defined in this file are not loaded.

It is possible to use this approach, or I need to register a service provider to load custom route files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to map routes in your **RouteServiceProvider.php**, Check the example of web routes.

```
   /**
     * Define the "web" routes for the application.
     *
     * These routes all receive session state, CSRF protection, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function mapWebRoutes()
    {
        Route::group([
            'middleware' => 'web',
            'namespace' => $this->namespace,
        ], function ($router) {
            require base_path('routes/web.php');
        });
    }
```

Comment: So, can I just require my other file inside this anonymous function, after requiring the web.php file?

Comment: Yes, you can :)